# Accessory type pushes tableviewcell to left

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview cell shown like this…

[image]

In the above tableview, I am showing an accessory type checkmark for selection. For that I have set this in the UITableViewCell class…

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

  if selected {
    editingAccessoryType = .checkmark
  } else {
    editingAccessoryType = .none
  }
}
```

But this pushes my tableviewcell to the left like so...

[image]

How can I avoid this and have the accessory type checkmark appear within the cell itself...?

Comment: NO, you need to take new button/ UIImageView and use it.

Comment: Is this a default behaviour of accessory type checkmark...?

Comment: Yes, and you can't override it.

Comment: Tableview cell's content view width shrinks when you have an `editingAccessoryType`. You should use a white background for your cell. Not for cell subviews

Comment: @RajeshKumarR And thats how gray color between cells also turned into white.

Comment: @dahiya_boy for cell padding section footer can be used and no of sections should return no of rows. Each section will have one cell

Comment: @asd2 Another approach is adding a custom uiimage view for selected cells. You can use any one of these answers

Comment: ok  @dahiya_boy and RajeshKumar R..thanks for the inputs..:)I have used a uiview and added an imageview within it...and it's working fine...

Answer (score 0):

you can put your cell background to white instead of your view so this can appear as you want.